# Weird first line indentation in verse after ragged2e ending in line break

Tags: verse, ragged2e

In a multi-author project, I noticed a weird indentation in the first line of a `verse` environment directly following any `ragged2e` environment if it ends in a line break (`\\`):

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ragged2e,verse}

\begin{document}

\begin{FlushLeft}
    Hallo\\
    Hallo\\
\end{FlushLeft}

\begin{verse}
    Hallo\\
    Hallo
\end{verse}

\end{document}
```

[image: Weird indent after trailing line break]

This doesn't happen when removing the trailing line break, or when using the non-ragged2e equivalent environment (`flushleft` in this case):

[image: No indent in regular environment]

Of course, this is easily fixable by removing the (unnecessary) trailing line break, but since this is a multi-author project, I'd like to achieve a more generic solution. In the actual document, the contents of both environments are given as arguments to commands, so there's some headroom for ‘patching’ solutions.

Comment: the environment form is `FlushLeft` not `RaggedRight`  (or leave a blank line before ending the environment)

Comment: ooh, above comment is true but does not help you as FlushLeft shows same issue

Comment: Huh, you're right. I originally used `Center`, but that was a bit inconvenient for the screenshot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug and totally my fault. I prepared a fix in the ragged2e repo and will release a new version of ragged2e after I finished the testing. I can add a note here after it's done.

Comment: Thanks to CTAN it's already installed there and syncing though the mirrors atm.

Answer (score 4):

With ragged2e every line is actually a paragraph. And the `\\` command is redefined and adds (globally) code to the begin of the next paragraph which removes its indent.

So if you have a `\\` after the last line the next paragraph will have no indent, and in a list like the verse environment it confuses the spacing. You can clear the hook (but better would be not to end paragraphs and similar with `\\`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{verse}
\AddToHook{env/RaggedRight/after}{\ClearHookNext{para/begin}}
\begin{document}

\begin{RaggedRight}
    Hallo\\
    Hallo\\    
\end{RaggedRight}

\begin{verse}
    Hallo\\
    Hallo
\end{verse}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ragged2e,verse}

\begin{document}

\begin{FlushLeft}
    Hallo\\
    Hallo\\
\end{FlushLeft}

\begin{verse}
    Hallo\\
    Hallo
\end{verse}

\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

In texlive 2021 or older and

[image]

in texlive 2022 or later.

Which means one of the packages needs an update, probably to match paragraph hook additions in the format.

The packages are probably easily updatable (I will look later) but until then not having a trailing `\\`  is simplest (also use the `Flush...` environment forms not the `Ragged..`  forms which are intentended for command use. Similar to the standard latex `flushleft` being the environment form of `\raggedright`)

Comment: Ah, that explains why I hadn't noticed it before.